# Filter one datagridview and keep relation to another

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, dataset

I got two `datasets` with two `datatables`. Binded and displayed on two `datagrids`:

```
//fill datatable
companiesDataTable = new DataTable("Companies");
scheduleDataTable = new DataTable("Schedule");
adapterCompanies.Fill(companiesDataTable);
adapterSchedule.Fill(scheduleDataTable);

//set dataset
myDataSet = new DataSet();
myDataSet.Tables.Add(companiesDataTable);
myDataSet.Tables.Add(scheduleDataTable);

//add relation
myDataSet.Relations.Add("FullSchedule",
                        myDataSet.Tables["Companies"].Columns["id"],
                        myDataSet.Tables["Schedule"].Columns["CompanyID"]);

//set binding sources
bsComp = new BindingSource(myDataSet, "Companies");
bsSched = new BindingSource(bsComp, "FullSchedule");

//fill datagrid
dataGridViewCompanies.DataSource = bsComp;
dataGridViewTimes.DataSource = bsSched;
```

How can i filter companies `datagrid` without loosing relation to schedule `datagrid`?

I tried this, but relation seems to be lost:

```
var view = myDataSet.Tables["Companies"].DefaultView;
view.RowFilter = filterString;                
dataGridViewCompanies.DataSource = view;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well ok, this was embarrassingly simple:

```
            bsComp.Filter = filterString;
            dataGridViewCompanies.DataSource = bsComp;
```